# Memory leak, using Sequelize ORM for NodeJS

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, orm, sequelize.js, pm2

I'm trying to use this Sequelize ORM stuff for my project. I've integrated it as on example https://github.com/sequelize/express-example. So, cool - for now it's working with all relations and other goods. The problem is, that pm2 show's that my memory usage grows and never coming back.

This is my test script, that eats 100 Mb of RAM per launch.  Have I missed something?

```
router.get('/test', hutils.authChecker, function(req, res, next) {
    Project.findById(1,{ include : [Player]}).then(function(project) {
        return Promise.denodeify(async.map)(project.Players, function(player, callback) {
            Player.create({
                project_id : 1,
                name       : 'iter_'+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)+Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000)
            }).then(function(gamer) {
                callback(null, gamer)
            });
        });
    }).then(function(plrs) {
        return Promise.denodeify(async.map)(plrs, function(guy, callback) {
            guy.update({name : sqlRequest+'zzzzz'+Math.random()}).then(function(number) {
                callback(null, number);
            });
        });
    }).then(function(numbers) {
        return Player.findAll({where : {name : {$like : '%zzzzz%'}}});
    }).then(function(zets) {
        return Promise.denodeify(async.map)(zets, function(zet, callback) {
            zet.destroy().then(function(number) {
                callback(null, number);
            });
        });
    }).catch(function(err) {
        next(err);
    });
});
```

P.S. It`s make no sense, just to look how the ORM works. If it's matter, i have 1k players, for this project.

Answer (score 0):

In queries that have results with a lot of rows, all of them will get loaded into memory before the callback.

So in this example, the query `Project.findById(1,{ include : [Player]})` deserializes project 1 and all of its 1,000 players into JavaScript objects before returning them in the `.then(function(project)`.   Furthermore, the array of `plrs`, `numbers` and `zets` are all similarly stored in memory before they get returned thus increasing memory usage.

A way around this would be to get the database to do the heavy lifting.  For example don't return each `gamer` that gets created and instead perform a update query on the db.

```
Player.update({
  name : sqlRequest + 'zzzzz' + Math.random(),
}, {
  where: {
    createdAt: {
      $gte: new Date() // or some other filter condition that identifies the records you need.
    }
  }
});
```

And then instead of destroying each `zet`, perform a delete query on the db.

```
Player.destroy({
  where: {
    name : {
      $like : '%zzzzz%'
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the attention, but like i said: ` It`s make no sense, just to look how the ORM works.`. I wont do that insane query`s on prod server :).
The main question is, why my memory usage grows and never coming back.
Player.find({where : {project_id : 1}}); - if i do something like that, ammm.. 1000 times in row, without even saving the result - it`s still takes large memory pice, and dont clean it after! :(